# How to add a native C-module to a node project?

Tags: node.js

I created a node project and for a specific function, I need to create a custom native C-module. I created a *Hello World* project and moved it into a sub directory of my node project (called **my-native-module**). It contains the `bindings.gyp`, the `hello-world.c`, etc.

How can I now embed this into the project itself without making it an external project? How would I compile this? Is there a specific `npm` command for this?

Here is the current directory structure of my project, with the native-module inside

```
+ my-native-module/...
|  - binding.cc
|  - binding.gyp
|  - package.json
|  - package-lock.json
|
+ node_modules/
|  - ...
|  - ...
| 
+ src/
|  - foo1.js
|  - foo2.js
| 
- package.json
- package-lock.json
```

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by "How can I now embed this into the project itself without making it an external project?". How do you intend to make your project available? Will `my-native-module` be included in your project when distributed (either publicly or privately) or made available at a remote location?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't understand. Embedding means including in an existing project, not external shipping on a remote dependency. Isn't that what embedding means? Basically I would like to try to import my 'hello-world' module which is written in C/C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First tell npm that you are using gyp by setting `"gypfile": true` and by adding `build` and `clean` commands to scripts in package.json

```
{
    "name": "application",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "using gyp",
    "main": "index.js",
    "gypfile": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node src/foo1.js",
        "test": "your test commands",
        "build": "node-gyp rebuild",
        "clean": "node-gyp clean"
    }
}
```

Then you add the binding.gyp file to the root of your project directory
with a content like this:

```
{
"targets": [
    {
       "target_name": "c_module_name",
       "sources": [
           "my-native-module/binding.cc"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

run the project with `npm start`, if its necessary run `npm run build` to build the c module

now you can import it with

```
var c_module = require('../build/Release/c_module_name.node');//if it is imported from src/*.js
```

When deployed npm will handle the gyp building process

now the project is like this:

```
+ my-native-module/...
|  - binding.cc
|
+ node_modules/
|  - ...
|  - ...
| 
+ src/
|  - foo1.js
|  - foo2.js
| 
- binding.gyp
- package.json
- package-lock.json
```

Note: c module needs to be written in nodeapi